# ASP.net Redirect from gridview to another page showing details from database

Tags: asp.net

currently I have data in gridview (from sql server) and i want to click and redirect to another webpage showing its detail also from the database.

Can anyone please help me.

and I want detail view through textbox or label (retrieve from db)

thank you.

Alan

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].

Comment: Sorry, is my question wrong sir?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GridViewRowCommand to check which row is clicked and get the details related to that id and put the details in some session and in same event redirect page to whichever page you want and there you  can get back your details from that particular session and can show the details in label or whatever control you want to show.